# What limits exist with Youtube Data API V3 BESIDES the quota allocation?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My client has an application that allows users to upload videos to youtube from a mobile application.  They are first uploaded to the client's server, and then that server uploads them to youtube via the Youtube Data API V3 package from google.  As traffic has picked up, the application has periods where the upload process returns a 400 error, and the uploads to YouTube fail.  This usually lasts an hour and a half or so, and then the uploads begin working again.

I have already checked the Quota limits in the Developer Console area.  We are not exceeding the daily quota.  I also noticed the client was not using the QuotaUser field (or the deprecated UserIP field), so the next outage I ran a test to see if setting that would alleviate the stoppage, it did not. I also tried uploading from a different IP, in case the client's server IP was just being blocked temporarily, and that did not work either.

Is there a maximum number of videos upload limit in a given time period, or some other limiting factor BESIDES the quota limits?

Comment: I build a postman request, and got back the following : 

`{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "youtube.video",
                "reason": "uploadLimitExceeded",
                "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "youtube.video",
            "reason": "uploadLimitExceeded",
            "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
        }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
}
}
```

Evidently they limit the number of videos you can upload a day.  Averaging historical data, it appears to be ~100 a day.  Must be broken into smaller chunks, as the service comes back after much less than 24 hours.